# Word for sleeping somewhere for one night

Tags: single-word-requests

I was wondering if there is a word that means to stay/sleep somewhere for only one night.

Here are a couple examples:

> Abraham's servant decided to *word* at Rebecca's family's house.
>
> The kind couple suggested to the poor man that he *word* at their house.

If more examples are needed, I will gladly supply.

Comment: "Overnight" is the word.  "... decided to *overnight* at Rebecca's ..."

Comment: What’s wrong with ***sleep*** ?

Comment: In Britain one would say *stay*, or if needing to emphasise a single night's visit *stay the night*.

Comment: In my mind those are what *someone else* does  *for* you-  he *put me up* for the night.   Joe *fixed me up* [with a place to stay] for the night.

Comment: If we really are talking Old Testament here, the James I , 1611 version, would probably use *abide*.

Comment: For me “he fixed himself up a place to stay...” means he *created” the place, maybe by building a shelter or laying down cardboard or using branches and grass to make a bed...

Comment: You might use "couch" as a verb.  Or maybe "airbnb".

Comment: The word would be overnight or sleepover

Comment: Colloquially the word ```crash``` could be used. "The kind couple suggested to the poor man that he crash at their house." But ```sleep over``` may work even better as it fits the slightly old fashioned sense of the sentence.

Comment: `stay over` is also possible

Comment: [*Make me a pallet on the floor*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=39RBm4tH9cA).

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Abraham's servant decided to *stay the night* at Rebecca's family's house.

The kind couple suggested to the poor man that he *stay the night* at their house.

Comment: Also _spend_ the night.

Comment: True... but I think he wants an older version where it's impossible to interpret like "sleeping" with the other person. The old 80s movies ruined "spend" the night for everyone.

Comment: @unmircea "spend the night *at X's house*" seems much more innocent than "--*with X*"; for a plural X, it's somewhere in between.

Comment: @user1359: *Spend the night* was already given as an answer.

Comment: @unmircea: 80s movies didn't ruin *spend the night* for everyone, not for me, at least. Of course, perhaps we didn't watch the same "80s movies". ;-)

Answer (score 37):

I think that the word you are looking for might be "crash".

**Example:**

> "You can crash at my place if you like."

Comment: Exactly the word in my mind. However, its rather informal...

Comment: Not perhaps suitable for Abrahan's servant, though?

Comment: True, very informal. However, maybe this Abraham is very cool one ;)

Comment: We are talking about people with Old Testament names. And there is a 'servant' involved. *Crash* seems to me what a 2015 student does when he stays over at his mate's place, usually involving sleeping on an air-bed if he's lucky, on the floor if he isn't.

Comment: @WS2 Well, we did this when I was a student, too, which was almost that long ago :)

Comment: If we are talking patriarchs and Philemon and Baucis, maybe it is time to drag *[sojourn](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sojourn)* out of mothballs.

Comment: To me, sojourn is a temporary stay, but not necessarily (and not likely) one of a single night's duration.  The Israelites sojourned in the land of Goshen.  I doubt it was a one-nighter.

Comment: "For that night, Abraham's servant crashed at Rebecca's house for Netflix and Chill. That next morning, behold, there was indeed a walk of shame." Just doesn't have the right ring to it.

Comment: *Crash* does not imply a single night.

Answer (score 26):

*Abraham's servant decided to **overnight** at Rebecca's family's house.*

*The kind couple suggested to the poor man that he **overnight** at their house.*

*The story is told of how Gamzu was sent to Rome with a gift for the Emperor - a chest full of gold and jewels. Along the way, he stopped to [overnight](http://sholomravsermons.blogspot.fr/) at an inn.*

*We [overnighted](http://global.oup.com/booksites/content/9780199238392/solutions/solutions.pdf) in Mannheim, but Maria stayed overnight in Ludwigshafen*.

[overnight](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/overnight): to stay overnight

Comment: If you hadn't included the link, I would have never have believed that "overnight" can be used as a verb. But the fact that it can, doesn't mean it is well-known or acceptable to the majority of native speakers. I'm guessing that this is AmEng dialect. Imagine someone asking: "Can I overnight at your place?" OR "Will you be overnighting?" Too *awful* for words. :)

Comment: @Mari-LouA It doesn't sound that terrible to my ear...maybe t's just a matter of "getting acclimated" with it. :-) It's even been around as a verb for quite awhile actually: since about the end of the 19th century! Plus, more recently, it has deceloped in AmEng into the meaning of "to send by overnight mail." It is much more used in speech than in writing though, but that doesn't mean it is not acceptable in your correspondence, or that you need to put quotes around it when you use it...:-) Assuming that the reader will readily understand what is meant, there's no reason to avoid this verb.

Comment: @Mari-LouA http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/overnight

Comment: @Mari-LouA: I agree that "Will you be overnighting?" sounds bad, like an artificial phrase that came out of a marketing department somewhere.  I think the word is more than fine for formal use, though, and have heard it before.  Your first example sounds a bit informal, so "crash" would fit well.

Comment: "stayed overnight" seems most natural to me.  Not a single word, but more natural than "overnighted".

Comment: @Mari-LouA Agreed.  It sounds like marketer jargon.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I find it natural. People overnight, birds and beasts overwinter :) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overwintering

Comment: This was actually the first thing that came to mind when I read the question (AmE native). I'll admit it sounds a bit outdated to me, but not unusual.

Answer (score 15):

I thought the word was [pernoctate](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/pernoctate) - probably not used very much these days.

Comment: +1 This is exactly correct, but almost certainly not what the OP was after.

Comment: @jamesh It would be helpful if you edited your answer to add a reference, and maybe a link.  "Pernoctate" is new to me, and I'd have immediately clicked on a link to its definition, if it had been there.

Comment: Indeed, this is a new word to me, and is next in line as the title of a poem.

Comment: Interestingly, Merriam-Webster has a somewhat [different definition](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pernoctate), to stay up or out, especially in vigil.

Answer (score 12):

An expression for this is "*spend the night*". That's not a single word, unless you are just looking for "*spend*".

- I spent the night at X's house.

Comment: It should be highlighted that 'spend the night' is also a euphemism for having sex.

Comment: @dwjohnston: No, it should not. There is hardly any way of saying the same thing that cannot be used to suggest having sex. In such a case, "euphemism" means nothing.

Comment: @dwjohnston: there is a difference between 'spend the night with' and 'spend the night at'.

Answer (score 7):

What is wrong with with 'sleep'? Keep it simple, rather than try and find some elaborate word which everyone would have to look up anyway.  Unless you're looking for a word that fits into the period in which you're writing.

Answer (score 4):

The word "sojourn" refers to a temporary stay (though not necessarily one night), has Latin roots, and has recorded use since mediaeval times.

Answer (score 4):

If I needed to stay somewhere for a night, I might ask:

> Can I **bunk** with you tonight?

Note, this does not typically imply anything beyond an intent to sleep at a persons house.

Additionally:

> Abraham's servant decided to **bunk** at Rebecca's family's house.
>
> The kind couple suggested to the poor man that he **bunk** at their house.

Comment: Doesn't imply a single night, however.

Answer (score 3):

How about ["stop over" (Cambridge)](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/stop-over)?  Without more than one night being specified, a single night stay is implied (at least as I hear/use it), and the stay is secondary to some other activity, such as a journey or a late event.

Comment: This was the first thing I thought of, though it admittedly doesn't fit the 'Abraham's servant' example well at all.

Comment: @Brian I wasn't sure it was a biblical reference, and didn't want to assume. All alternatives to the horrible "overnight" as a verb should be explored.

Comment: Yep, it's from when Abraham sent his servant to seek out a wife for Isaac.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite one word, but how does "bed down" sound? As per the Cambridge Dictionaries Online, http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bed-down, to ​lie down ​somewhere, *usually ​somewhere different from where you usually ​sleep*, in ​order to go to ​sleep

Comment: It sounds very informal.

Comment: Agreed, I definitely would not use it when referring to a head of state or someone like that. However, don't you think a formal event would tend towards politically-correct (and thus generally longer) turns of phrase? In which case, the one-word condition may be overlooked in favor of other considerations.

Comment: This is a phrase I might use if I was _camping_,

Answer (score 1):

*Sleepover* is common when referring to children.

Answer (score 1):

A phrase used quite often here in Scotland, but comes from Old English is [Bide](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/bide)

> Remain or Stay Somewhere:
>
> "How long must I bide here to wait for the answer>"

It's more commonly used to indicate "to live (somewhere)"

> "Where do you bide?" "On King St"

but it can also be used to indicate where you spent the night.

> Why don't you bide at my place tonight?

In your examples:

> Abraham's servant decided to *bide* at Rebecca's family's house.
>
> The kind couple suggested to the poor man that he *bide* at their house.

Answer (score 1):

Lots of suggestions, but I haven't seen this one yet: **[stay over](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/stay+over)**.

> stay over
>
> v.
>
> To spend the night: *The roads were icy, so we urged our
> guests to stay over. We stayed over in Denver and left the following
> morning.*

Answer (score 0):

You're *kipping* there. Do you want to *kip* at mine tonight? No problem.

Literally it's a synonym for "sleep", but with a casual, diminutive connotation that works well when applied to a temporary sleeping arrangement more generally. So, it doesn't exclusively mean what you asked for, but where I come from it's *almost* exclusively used as such.

Answer (score -2):

bivouac - back in my army reservists days, overnighters where called bivouac...

Comment: Bivouac means to camp without cover at all, so you can't do this at someone's house...unless you deliberately choose to sleep on their lawn.

Comment: Another term of military origin which is more applicable is "billet".